# Do I have to specify a version for Play 3rd party dependencies?

Tags: dependencies, playframework

I was trying to add a dependency on [StringTemplates](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.antlr/stringtemplate/3.2). This is how my dependencies.yml file looked like:

```
require:
    - play -> secure
    - play -> crud
    - org.antlr -> stringtemplate
```

And I got errors. When I added a specific version of stringtemplate:

```
    - org.antlr -> stringtemplate 4.0.2
```

everything worked.

So, just to make sure I understand - I have to specify a version or range of versions for a 3rd party dependency, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third party dependency management uses the Maven/Ivy scheme (because it is based on Ivy), which translates to a file name of `{name}-{version}.jar`.
While I think it is possible to simply use the latest version (either with SNAPSHOT as version or some wildcard, but I'm no expert here), it seems to be best practice to make versioning explicit.

Comment: you can also use version ranges like [1.0,)

more info here:
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/dependency#Dynamicrevisions